# Disable camel-debezium-mysql endpoint URI in Camel metrics

Tags: mysql, apache-camel, debezium

The full Debezium MySQL URI string shows up in metrics. It shows the MySQL user and password in plaintext, which is unsafe. How can one disable this? I followed this setup [here](https://debezium.io/blog/2020/02/19/debezium-camel-integration/).

More information:

Using `quarkus 1.11.1.Final` which uses `camel 3.7.0 with debezium-connector-mysql 1.3.1.Final`

This is the Camel route:

```
from("debezium-mysql:" + config.getConnectorName()
            + "?databaseHostname=" + config.getHost()
            + "&databasePort=" + config.getPort()
            + "&databaseUser=" + config.getUser()
            + "&databasePassword=" + config.getPassword()
            + "&databaseServerName=" + config.getDatabaseServerName()
            + "&databaseServerId=" + config.getDatabaseServerId()
            + "&databaseIncludeList=" + config.getDatabases()
            + "&tableIncludeList=" + config.getTables()
            + "&columnIncludeList=" + config.getColumns()
            + "&databaseHistoryFileFilename=" + config.getHistoryFile()
            + "&offsetStorageFileName=" + config.getStorageFile()
            + "&exchangePattern=InOnly")
            .routeId("debezium")
            .process(outgoingProcessor)
            .marshal().json(JsonLibrary.Jackson)
            .to(ExchangePattern.InOnly, outgoingUri)
            .to("micrometer:counter:outgoing.counter")
            .end();
```

And when accessing the metrics at `/q/metrics`, I find this entry:

```
# HELP CamelExchangeEventNotifier_seconds_max
# TYPE CamelExchangeEventNotifier_seconds_max gauge
CamelExchangeEventNotifier_seconds_max{camelContext="camel-1", endpointName="debezium-mysql://entire connection string here with user and password", eventType="ExchangeCompletedEvent", failed="false", serviceName="MicrometerEventNotifierService",} 0.0
```

Comment: What version of Camel do you use? And can you explain more exactly what metrics, eg is it via camel-metrics, or JMX or some UI dashboard, in a log file or what?

Comment: @ClausIbsen updated question with more info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for bring this up. I have created [a Jira ticket](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-16265) to fix this in the upcoming Camel release to mask those sensitive data in those events in the metrics.